# Pandas: Extract acronym from substrings of one column and match it to another column with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I am trying to match the names in two columns in the same dataframe, I want to create a function to return True if the name in one column is an acronym of the other even if they contain the same acronym substring.

```
pd.DataFrame([['Global Workers Company gwc', 'gwc'], ['YTU', 'your team united']] , columns=['Name1','Name2'])
```

Desired Output:

```
         Name1                      Name2               Match
0   Global Workers Company gwc           gwc            True
1   YTU                             your team united    True
```

I have creating a lambda function to only get the acronym but haven't been able to do so

```
t = 'Global Workers Company gwc'
[x[0] for x in t.split()]

['G', 'W', 'C', 'g']

"".join(word[0][0] for word in test1.Name2.str.split()).upper()
```

Comment: is that deliberate for row 1, the abbreviation is present with the full name?

Comment: yes, I want a condition in the function that accounts for something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Dataframe.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function along with `axis=1` parameter to apply a custom `func` on the dataframe. Then you can use regular expressions to compare the `acronym` with the corresponding *larger name or phrase.*

**Try this:**

```
import re

def func(x):
    s1 = x["Name1"]
    s2 = x["Name2"]

    acronym = s1 if len(s1) < len(s2) else s2
    fullform = s2 if len(s1) < len(s2) else s1

    fmtstr = ""
    for a in acronym:
        fmtstr += (r"\b" + a + r".*?\b")

    if re.search(fmtstr, fullform, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        return True
    else:
        return False


df["Match"] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                        Name1             Name2  Match
0  Global Workers Company gwc               gwc   True
1                         YTU  your team united   True
```

Comment: great answer! could you please explain what the regex pattern in fmtstr += (r"\b" + a + r".*?\b") is? How exactly does it work?

Comment: Consider the acronym is `gwc` and larger phrase is `Global Workers Company gwc`, So what we are essentially doing is that we are constructing a regular expression pattern which looks like `r"\bg.*?\b\bw.*?\b\bc.*?\b"` which exactly matches  a phrase like `Global Workers Company` that has each of words starting corresponding to respective individual characters of the acronym.

Comment: does it exclude "gwc" from the fullform word?

I tried using this function

def match_acro2(row):
    
    name1 = row['Name1']
    name2 = row['Name2']
    
    result1 = [''.join(x[0] for x in name if x != name1) for name in name2.split()][0]
    
    result2 = [''.join(x[0] for x in name if x != name2) for name in name1.split()][0]
        
    return (result1, result2)

but got the wrong results

test.apply(match_acro2, axis=1)

Output:
0    (gwc, Global)
1      (your, YTU)

Anyway you could please tell me what I did wrong here?I was trying to return the actual words

Comment: Yes it does exclude `gwc`.

Answer (score 0):

I will use a mapper.  We will have a lookup dictionary that will transform data to the same type that we can check for equality.

```py
import pandas as pd

#data
df = pd.DataFrame([['Global Workers Company', 'gwc'], ['YTU', 'your team united']] , columns=['Name1','Name2'])


# create a mapper
mapper = {'gwc':'Global Workers Company',
          'YTU': 'your team united'}

def replacer(value, mapper=mapper):
     '''Takes in value and finds its map, 
        if not found return original value
     '''
    return mapper.get(value, value)

# create column checker and assign the equality 
df.assign(
    checker = lambda column: column['Name1'].map(replacer) == column['Name2'].map(replacer)
)

print(df)
```